# Magento 2 magmi Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'curw.product_id' in 'on clause' -

Tags: magento2, magmi

Facing issue in product import when using   `On the fly indexer v0.2` plugin:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem in in file:

```
plugins/extra/itemprocessors/itemindexer/otfindexer.php
```

L:292 replace

```
JOIN {$this->tns["curw"]} as curw ON curw.product_id=cpe.entity_id
```

with

```
JOIN {$this->tns["curw"]} as curw ON curw.entity_id=cpe.entity_id
```